# If $f(x)$ is close to $0$ then necessarily $x$ is close to $\ker f$?

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Suppose that $X$ is a real Banach space and $f:X \to \mathbb{R}$ is a continuous linear functional. Is it true that for any $\varepsilon>0$ there is a $\delta>0$ such that for any $x \in X$ we have: $$|f(x)|<\delta \Rightarrow (\exists z \in \ker f) (\Vert x-z \Vert <\varepsilon).$$

This is certainly true if $X=\mathbb{R}^n$. I suspect this might be false for infinite-dimensional $X$, but I haven´t been able to find a counterexample.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you know quotient spaces and the quotient norm?

Comment: Suppose that $f$ is not zero, let $u$ (fixed) such that $f(u)=1$, use $z=x-f(x)u$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $f$ is identically $0$ there is nothing to show. Otherwise pick $x_0$ such that $f(x_0)\neq 0$ and write $x$ as 
$$x=x-\frac{f(x)}{f(x_0)}x_0+\frac{f(x)}{f(x_0)}x_0.$$
If we define $z(x):=x-\frac{f(x)}{f(x_0)}x_0$, then $z\in\ker f$ and 
$\lVert x-z(x)\rVert=\frac{|f(x)|}{|f(x_0)]}\lVert x_0\rVert$, hence 
$\delta:=\frac{\varepsilon}{\lVert x_0\rVert}|f(x_0)|$ does the job.

Comment: Thank you very much Davide, I guess you meant $\delta:=\frac{\varepsilon}{\Vert x_0 \Vert}|f(x_0)|$.

Comment: Yes, fixed now.